# How do I get the node ID from the taxonomy term ID?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

In Drupal 7, we are using `taxonomy_select_nodes()` to get a list of nodes using a taxonomy term.

What is the equivalent in versions after Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [loadByProperties()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageInterface.php/function/EntityStorageInterface%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.3.x):

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties(['field_tags' => $tid]);
```

Comment: Does it work also for field values?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, this works for all field values.

Comment: It's working but when i Switch language same node id return .I need to return nid behalf of language .

Comment: In D8 all translations of a node have the same node id. When you render the node the language switches automatically to the current language.